# React is not defined when using react-jsonschema-form

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

Example of the problem here : https://codesandbox.io/s/spike-react-starter-6xkwx

I try to use `react-jsonschema-form` and `react-jsonschema-form-conditionals` with a custom widget :

```
export const MoneyWidget = props => {
  return <div>{props.value}</div>
}

export const uiSchema = {
  money: {
    'ui:widget': MoneyWidget
  }
}
```

However, I keep having a `React not defined` or a `_objectWithoutProperties2` error. I would like to know if you could help solve this problem please Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with `react-jsonschema-form-condtionals`. To drill down further, here is what is happening:

> Any custom widget with conditional rules is working only with a babel transpiled version. Else React undefined error pops up.

To justify this, instead of

```
export const MoneyWidget
```

If you do

```
export const TextField
```

everything will start working; since TextField is a already a babel transpiled component.

Now, to get the MoneyWidget working in similar manner, if you use webpack or just as proof of concept online babel transpiler, you will get code blocks transpiled from

```
import React from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

function MoneyWidget(props) {
  return <div>{props.value}</div>
}

export default MoneyWidget
```

to

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
})
exports.MoneyWidget = void 0

var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require('react'))

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
  return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }
}

var MoneyWidget = function MoneyWidget(props) {
  return /*#__PURE__*/ _react.default.createElement('div', null, 
     props.value)
}

exports.MoneyWidget = MoneyWidget
```

Once you use this version, flow will start showing up your custom widget as well, along with all the rules working.

Here is a working version with all the comments around this added in a new `MoneyWidget.jsx` component file

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverlfow-spike-react-starter-8jp5o

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, it works but the issue now is that when the widget uses react components from external libraries, these components also have to be transpiled so it is a bit hard to work with and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

On UISchema.jsx, you can't use  tag under MoneyWidget.

The following works without any errors.

```
export const MoneyWidget = props => {
  return props.value
}
```